# Loading pdf in web browser control with requireAdministrator UIaccess does not render pdf properly

Tags: pdf, vb6, webbrowser-control

I have a small vb6 application where I show PDF files in a web browser control. So I navigate to a required file using “WebBrowser1.Navigate”.  It works well and the pc should have adobe reader installed.
But I have observed some strange behavior in windows 8 pcs (checked in about 4 PC).

If the application has asInvoker  level manifest then pdf appear proper as expected.

If the application has requireAdministrator 
level manifest then pdf does not appear and blank page appears.(so pdf is not rendered).Same problem comes for highestAvailable level if user is administrator.

I have observed loading webpage does not have this kind of problems.

So why the strange behaviour is shown if a application run as Administrator.

You can download the file from [this link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2B635F7D896B131!154&authkey=!AO6WqlgMqHg8ilI&ithint=file%2Czip) and check the said error.(EXE are already created with different manifest levels). Or adding web browser control to a form and just add WebBrowser1.Navigate("path to pdf") .Even no need to add manifest .running by using right click run as administrator gives error.

Comment: This may or may not have anything to do with your problem: the administrator account can't run the built-in PDF viewer in Windows 8. It can only be run from a non-administrator user account. I don't know whether the web browser control will use that built-in PDF viewing app. I believe opening a PDF using file extension associations does use the built-in PDF viewing app.

Comment: @MarkJ In my pc adobe reader is default for pdf file. It does use adobe reader in both cases . I have verified it using processexplorer. Have you checked running in your pc?

Comment: You are right, if Process Explorer says its Adobe Reader in your failure cases, then my observation doesn't help you. Sorry! BTW it is unlikely anyone will try running your EXE on their machines, just because everyone is paranoid about malware.

Comment: @MarkJ Yea. But anyone can try the error by adding web browser control to a form and just add WebBrowser1.Navigate("path to pdf") .Even no need to add manifest .running by using right click run as administrator gives error.

Comment: That's better, but I don't have a Windows 8 machine handy right now, sorry.

Comment: Anyone tried to create the problem i faced?